# grant permission to a user to create application roles

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, authentication

how to grant permission to a user to create application roles? i used  :

`grant execute on sp_addapprole to bobDBUser`  , but it says :

Permissions on server scoped catalog views or system stored procedures or extended stored procedures can be granted only when the current database is master.

then i changed to master database. 
then on executing this, it says that user bobDBUser not found. because the user was created inside bobDB, not master. so how do i do it for bobDB?

Comment: Delete `bobDBUser` from the specific database user entries (won't let you recreate in the master if it already exists AFAIK), then create `bobDBUser` in the master user entries, then assign the user to the specific database. This should do the trick, however, is not a definitive answer, hence the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the same user on `master`.